# How are activator and Play! linked?

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

Is this correct ? :

The Scala activator is build on the pLay framework and provides templates and environments for creaeting and deploying reactive applications.

If download the Play! activator also includes Play! framework can Play! tasks such as `play dist` be run from within the activator ? As `play` command is not included with activator download ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activator replaces the Play command in the Play Framework (which **was** also a wrapper around sbt). See [here](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/typesafe-activator-what-is-it).

According to [Play docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#Running-a-production-server-in-place), you should be able to do that. :)